# Trying to Solve the Black Scholes PDE with the Green's Function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finance, greens-function, step-function

I have finished the transformation into the Heat Equation.  And I am now at the point of establishing the initial conditions.  The article I read said the $\max(S-K,0)$ is now the initial condition rather than the terminal condition, which I agree.

1. But then the article said that $u_0(x) \equiv K(e^{\max(x,0)} - 1) \theta(x)$ with $\theta(x)$ being the Heaviside Step Function.  I have a vague idea of $\theta(x)$ being the derivative of max(x,0), but doesn't see how this comes together.
2. In solving the equation, I looked up the Green's Function for $\partial_t - k \partial^2_x$ ,which in my opinion is quite fitting, is $\theta(t)(\frac{1}{4 \pi k t})^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4kt}}$.  But the integral in that the article presented is $\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi \tau}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}u_0(y)e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2 \sigma^2 \tau}}dy$.  My question is why the hell is the $y$ term in the exponential.

Comment: By the way, I am attempting to solve the Heat Equation $\frac{\partial v}{\partial \tau} = \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}$.

Comment: 1. I am also bemused by the $\theta(x)$ because it doesn't do anything. If $x\le 0$ then $K\left(\exp\left\{\max(x,0)\right\}-1\right)=0$ anyway.
2. Your Green's function is the solution given an initial point mass at zero. To apply it to something more complicated (e.g. your pay-off function) you need to perform a *convolution*.

Comment: but how does the initial condition of max(S-K,0) transform into K(e^{max(x,0)}-1)theta(x)

Comment: To my knowledge, the green's function is the continous sum across a certain domain of the delta function times the green's function for the derivative.  Therefore, applying should be just using $u_0(y)$ as the delta function.  Please correct me.  I can't quite wrap my mind around this.  I am just trying to figure out the how to solve Black-Scholes Equation.

Comment: If $x=\ln(S/K)$ then $\max(S-K,0)=\max(K(\exp x-1),0)
=K(\exp\{\max(x,0)\}-1)$.

Comment: Yes $u_{0}(y)$ takes the place of $\delta(y)$ in the convolution $u(\tau,x)=1/(\sigma\sqrt(2\pi\tau))\int \delta(y)\exp\{-(x-y)^{2}/(2\sigma^{2}\tau)\}dy$ which for $\delta(y)$ evaluates to just
$u(\tau,x)=1/(\sigma\sqrt(2\pi\tau))\exp\{-x^{2}/(2\sigma^{2}\tau)\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot that makes perfect sense, if you would like to make that formal answer I would upvote it.  But for the second part of the answer, I agree with your conclusion, but the problem is that it disagrees with the notation in the article which says that there is a y term in the exponential.  And I believe green's function for the one-dimensional equation is $\theta(t)(\frac{1}{4 \pi k t})^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4kt}}$.  Can you make your derivation clearer, and post that as a formal answer.

Comment: I have also written a $y$ term in the exponential.

Comment: If the second equation is your answer it does not agree with the one I've seen in my material.

Comment: but only in the first equation, I believe

Comment: The second equation I wrote applies only for the delta.

Comment: Also, I don't see the integral on the second equation.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was not because you wrote u(tau,x) = ...

Comment: In that case, can you explain to me why is there a y term in the exponential, as there isn't one in the green's function of the one-dimensional diffusion.  And also it would be great if you post your answer as answer in more detail.  Thanks in advance.